# How to pull a specific html attribute into a variable

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

so the title is probably really badly worded but I was not sure how else to word it.  So I asked help to use beautifulsoup4 to scrape data and someone was kind enough to help me out.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#NJII 
params = {
    'action': 'vc_get_vc_grid_data',
    'tag': 'vc_basic_grid',
    'data[page_id]': 26,
    'data[shortcode_id]': '1524685605316-ae64dc93-e23d-3',
    '_vcnonce': 'b9fb62cf69' #Need to update this somehow
}
dateList = []
urlList = []
url = 'http://njii.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='vc_gitem-animated-block'):
    if re.search('2018', div.find('a')['href']):
        urlList.append(div.find('a')['href'])
        dateList.append(div.find('a')['href'])

#print(urlList)

count = 0;
while(count < len(dateList)):
    dateList[count] = re.search('[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}', dateList[count])
    dateList[count] = dateList[count].group()
    count = count + 1

print(dateList[1])
```

So this works almost perfectly for what I needed but then a problem occurred.  The website I need to scrape data for my project updatse the _vcnonce variable daily.  So my question really comes down to is that is it possible to get that specific html string into a variable.  So everytime I run the code it will update automatically.  Kind of like this

```
variable = w.e vcnonce attribute is
'_vcnonce': variable
```

or something like that.  This is for a project where I need to get information and I was able to use selenium and beautifulsoup for other websites.  But this one is just giving me problems no matter what.  So I try to use selenium also but it would not work and I am just not sure if I need the same parameters even with selenium.  Sorry for this long question.  Not sure what would be the best approach to this.

Comment: So what is the problem? Why you cannot pass variable as value of `'_vcnonce'` key? Where you get that value from?

Comment: @Andersson it seems like he needs to get that key before running the rest of his code. I'm wondering if he can get that key without actually having to login to anything. Just checked the page and it comes up blank.

Comment: If `_vcnonce` value comes from another request, then I guess OP is searching for [`requests-session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects), but I'm not sure as for now question is kinda broad

Comment: I agree.. I visit the site but can't get to the login area to see if there is anyway to get this key in the console.

Comment: Sorry for late answer.  The website won't show cuz that is not the actual address.  It is njii.com/events/.  When the guy helped me, he had to put the url as that as it was getting the response there for some reason.  Also, I think _vcnonce is coming from another request as it changes daily and the site in the code is I believe where it sends the request.  I will check the requests-session thing you linked soon when I get the chance.  Sorry for my poorly worded question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first obtain the value from the events page. This can then be used to make further requests. It is contained as an attribute inside a `div` element:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# First obtain the current nonce from the events page
r = requests.get("http://njii.com/events/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
vcnonce = soup.find('div', attrs={'data-vc-public-nonce':True})['data-vc-public-nonce']

#NJII 
params = {
    'action': 'vc_get_vc_grid_data',
    'tag': 'vc_basic_grid',
    'data[page_id]': 26,
    'data[shortcode_id]': '1524685605316-ae64dc93-e23d-3',
    '_vcnonce': vcnonce,
}
dateList = []
urlList = []

url = 'http://njii.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='vc_gitem-animated-block'):
    if re.search('2018', div.find('a')['href']):
        urlList.append(div.find('a')['href'])
        dateList.append(div.find('a')['href'])

dates = [re.search('[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}', date).group() for date in dateList]
print(dates)
```

This would give you an output as:

```
['2018/11/01', '2018/10/22', '2018/10/09', '2018/10/09', '2018/10/03', '2018/09/27', '2018/09/21', '2018/09/13', '2018/09/12', '2018/08/24', '2018/08/20', '2018/08/02', '2018/07/27', '2018/07/11', '2018/07/06', '2018/06/21', '2018/06/08', '2018/05/24', '2018/05/17', '2018/05/14', '2018/05/04', '2018/04/20', '2018/03/28', '2018/03/26', '2018/03/23', '2018/03/22', '2018/03/15', '2018/03/15', '2018/02/27', '2018/02/19', '2018/01/18']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was actually what I needed.  I was trying to do what you did wth the vcnonce but I just wasn't sure what to write.